# error when casting an image to different types in C++

Tags: c++11

I am trying to use the following sentences to cast an image to different types (the library I am using is ITK 5.1 if it helps):

```
  if (outputPixelType == std::string("double"))
  {
    using OutputPixelType = double;
  }
  else
  {
    using OutputPixelType = int;
  }

  using OutputImageType = itk::Image<OutputPixelType, Dimension>;
```

I get an error like this using the compiler clang

```
  error: use of undeclared identifier 'OutputPixelType'; did you mean 'outputPixelType'?
  using OutputImageType = itk::Image<OutputPixelType, Dimension>;
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     outputPixelType
```

But if I use the following sentences, it works.

```
  using OutputPixelType = int;
  using OutputImageType = itk::Image<OutputPixelType, Dimension>;
```

Why the `if` statement does not work? How to correct it? Thank you.

I have tried the following command using dovahin's comment:

```
  using OutputPixelType = (outputPixelType == std::string("double")) ? double : int16_t;
```

After compiling, I got a different error:

```
error: expected a type
  using OutputPixelType = (outputPixelType == std::string("double")) ? double : int16_t;
                          ^
error: type-id cannot have a name
  using OutputPixelType = (outputPixelType == std::string("double")) ? double : int16_t;
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: expected ')'
  using OutputPixelType = (outputPixelType == std::string("double")) ? double : int16_t;
                                           ^
note: to match this '('
  using OutputPixelType = (outputPixelType == std::string("double")) ? double : int16_t;
                          ^
error: expected ';' after alias declaration
  using OutputPixelType = (outputPixelType == std::string("double")) ? double : int16_t;
```

It seems that `using` does not take ()?A:B statement.

Comment: Have you tried replacing whole if else statement with ternary operator eg. using OutputPixelType = (outputPixelType == std::string("double")) ? double : int;

Comment: `using` statements are evaluated at compile time, your if statement at runtime. This can't work. The same applies to dovahin's suggestion. You can not pick types at runtime like that. If you explain why you are trying to do that, we might be able to suggest a solution to your underlying problem.

Comment: `outputPixelType` is an input, typed through command line by the user. I want to use `OutputPixelType` to define an image type like this: `using OutputImageType = itk::Image<OutputPixelType, Dimension>;` Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template):

```cpp
template<typename OutputPixelType>
void dostuff() {
   using OutputImageType = itk::Image<OutputPixelType, Dimension>;
   ...
}

void fun(std::string outputPixelType) {
  if (outputPixelType == std::string("double")) {
    dostuff<double>();
  } else {
    dostuff<int>();
  }
}
```